# Error when running app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

This is error in the log console that I get when I run my app. I don't understand where things are going wrong.

If anyone knows whats happening, this would be much appreciated.

```
2012-01-01 21:09:04.821 Grocery Finder[242:1f03] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: _kCFURLConnectionPrivateRunLoopMode
2012-01-01 21:09:05.121 Grocery Finder[242:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x341c98bf 0x344191e5 0x34121275 0x29e47 0x2ab91 0x375b46b5 0x3760faf1 0x375d0d21 0x375d0a71 0x375d078b 0x375d04ff 0x3758781b 0x3758cfb9 0x34cdeba7 0x36dfde8d 0x3419c2dd 0x3411f4dd 0x3411f3a5 0x309a3fcd 0x375a0743 0x207b 0x2034)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the log message states you are requesting an item at index 1 in an empty array.

```
[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can post your code for checking where you are trying to access to a out of bounds item in the NSArray.